# Make widget that will follow user behavior at webpage/web application

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, web-frameworks

I would like to make/implement an widget that will show statistics for specific user at webpage (number of clicks at some links or butons, etc.). Initial idea is that user can click at some small button in corner of window and widget with his statistics will appear. That will later also be packed as Firefox plug-in.

Regarding my present searches, I found that there are couple free tools (like AWStats, Webalizer,...) that are doing similar job, but I'm not sure is it possible to customize them and implement in manner that I need. Also I was looking for Google Analytics API, but it looks like much more complex tool than I need here.

Technologies that I thought to use are GWT (Google Web Toolkit), because other parts will be written in Java and in my readings I found many thumbs up for this technology. I have to mention that I’m beginner in GWT, as well as web development, but I have experience in desktop application development, so I’m not beginner in programming.

If you need more information feel free to ask, and I’ll do my best to make my questions as clear as possible! Thank you in advance!

Nemanja

Comment: My question is: which of these technologies would you suggest to use? Is it better to use Analytics API for such problem or implement GWT? Is there some other technology or approach that would be better in this situation? Good references for materials/examples like this would be more than welcome!